# $\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{2}<\infty$ and $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ a.e. implies weak convergence.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

> Suppose that each $f_{n}$ and $f$ are Lebesgue measurable functions
>   from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Prove that if $\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{2}<\infty$ and $f_{n}\rightarrow f$
>   a.e., then  $$ \int f_{n}g\ dx\rightarrow\int fg\ dx $$ for every
>   $g\in L^{2}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.

First, I use Egoroff's theorem. Except small measure, the convergence
is uniform. But measure of $\mathbb{R}$ except small measure is $\infty$.
So I stuck here. Can anyone help me?

(1st edition)

Let $g$ is in $C_{c}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.

Then $m(\text{supp}(g))<\infty$.

So above weak convergence becomes 
$$
\int_{\text{supp}(g)}f_{n}g\ dx\rightarrow\int_{\text{supp}(g)}fg\ dx.
$$
I write this form in the norm notation : 
$$
\|(f_{n}-f)g\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\longrightarrow0.
$$
To apply Erogoff on the left hand side : $\forall\epsilon>0$, there
exists measurable set $E$ such that $m(E)<\epsilon$ and $f_{n}\rightarrow f$
uniformly on $E^{c}$. Then 
$$
\|\left(f_{n}-f\right)g\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\|g\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\leq\|g\|\left(\int_{E}(f_{n}-f)\ dx+\int_{E^{c}}\left(f_{n}-f\right)\ dx\right).
$$

By uniform convergence, $(f_{n}-f)<\epsilon$ on $E^{c}$ by taking
$n$ large. And $\int_{E}\left(f_{n}-f\right)\ dx\leq2\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|m(E)<2\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|\epsilon$(This
is What Sangchul Lee mentioned below)(More detail, I used Holder inequality).

So 
$$
\|\left(f_{n}-f\right)g\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}<M\epsilon
$$
where $M$ is constant. If anyone has spare time, please check my
proof here.

Comment: You can't use Egoroff unless the domain of the functions has finite measure.

Comment: @Davey Oh yes yes. My fault

Comment: Hint: by density in $L^2$, it suffices to prove the result if $g$ is continuous with compact support.

Comment: @Gribouillis If $g$ is continuous compact support, I can use Egoroff on $f_{n}$. Then except small measure, $\| f_{n} -f\|$ is small, and on the small measure set, $\| f_{n} -f\|$ is bounded by the assumption. Is that right?

Comment: On the small measure set, you can prove by Cauchy-Schwartz that the $L^1$ norm of $f_n-f$ is small, independently of $n$. As the $C_0^0$ function $g$ is bounded, this does the trick. But all this needs to be precisely written.

Comment: @Gribouillis Let $E$ be that small measure set. Then $|\int_{E}(f_{n}-f)g|\leq\int_{E}|f_{n}-f||g|\leq\left(\int_{E}|f_{n}-f|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{E}|g|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|g\|_{L^{2}(E)}\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{2}\left(E\right)}<Am(E)<a\epsilon$.(Because $\sup\|f_{n}\|$ is bounded)
I meant this. So done. Am I going well?

Comment: Oh in my proof, I have to choose smaller $E$ to be $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^2 (E)}< \epsilon$

Comment: @Gribouillis Any conmment on my proof here?

Comment: $f_n$ does not converge strongly to $f$, so you can not have $\|f_n-f\|_2$ small in general. You can have $\|f_n-f\|_2$ tends to 0 for example if you are on a subset given by Egoroff's theorem such that the subset has finite measure and $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on this subset.

Comment: @Gribouillis As you said, I chose $E$ which has small measure. I think you didn't read my proof fully. Could you read my proof again, and comment for me?

Comment: I think it doesn't work this way. The fact that E has small measure doesn't imply that $\|f_n -f\|_{L^2(E)}$ is small. You could perhaps update the question with your detailed attempts.

Comment: @Gribouillis I edited. Please check my proof.

Comment: A proof of the assertion at the top is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2026464). The gist of it is: boundedness implies the existence of weakly convergent subsequences, pointwise a.e. convergence implies that $f$ is the only possible limit for a weakly convergent subsequence, hence the full sequence converges weakly to $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh. Thank you. 1) If the sequence is bounded, there exists a subsequence convergent weakly. 2) Since the original sequence is converge, the subsequence should converge weakly to $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I proved 1). So the theorem is proved. But I don't know why you mentioned the link 'here'. Is that related? (I read just a question of the link and a lemma at the answer.)

Comment: I linked the answer because it contains a proof. The situation here is exactly that of the corollary, with $q = 2$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh right. I really feel thankful to you and happy new year.

Comment: You're welcome. And a happy new year to you too.

Comment: @DanielFischer And also, this question should be on because I'd like to check my proof is okay, and if it is untrue, I want to find a proof which uses Egoroff theorem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "this question should be on". Your idea is sound, but in the execution, you have a couple of mistakes. I'll write an answer, but first I have something else to do for a short while.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I meant "this question should be going on for my proof review". I understand. I'll wait. I want to ask you where I did mistakes after you back.

Comment: Opps. You used Egoroff in your proof. I now know that. Then I just want to know where I did a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is sound, but there are a few glitches in the execution.

Let's define $S := \sup_n \lVert f_n\rVert_{2}$. First we note that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lVert f\rVert_2 \leqslant S$ by Fatou's lemma:

$$\int \lvert f\rvert^2\,dx = \int \liminf_{n\to\infty} \lvert f_n\rvert^2\,dx \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int \lvert f_n\rvert^2\,dx \leqslant S^2.$$

Next we note that due to the boundedness of $(f_n)$, it suffices to prove the assertion

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n g\,dx = \int fg\,dx\tag{1}$$

for a family $\mathscr{G}\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that spans a dense subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\mathscr{H} = \{ g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) : (1)\text{ holds}\}$. Trivially $0 \in \mathscr{H}$, and by the linearity of the integral, every linear combination of elements of $\mathscr{H}$ belongs to $\mathscr{H}$, so $\mathscr{H}$ is a linear subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Since $(f_n)$ is bounded, $\mathscr{H}$ is closed: Let $h \in \overline{\mathscr{H}}$. For every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $g\in \mathscr{H}$ with $\lVert g-h\rVert_2 \leqslant \varepsilon$, and hence

\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\: \Biggl\lvert \int (f_n - f)h\,dx\Biggr\rvert
&= \limsup_{n\to\infty}\: \Biggl\lvert \int (f_n - f)g\,dx + \int (f_n-f)(h-g)\,dx\Biggr\rvert \\
&\leqslant \limsup_{n\to \infty}\: \Biggl\lvert \int (f_n - f)g\,dx\Biggr\rvert + \limsup_{n\to \infty}\: \Biggl\lvert \int (f_n - f)(h-g)\,dx\Biggr\rvert \\
&= \limsup_{n\to \infty}\: \Biggl\lvert \int (f_n - f)(h-g)\,dx\Biggr\rvert \tag{$g\in\mathscr{H}$} \\
&\leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \:\lVert f_n -f \rVert_2\lVert h-g\rVert_2 \\
&\leqslant 2S\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Since that holds for all $\varepsilon > 0$, it follows that $h \in \mathscr{H}$.

So if $(1)$ holds for all $g \in \mathscr{G}$, it holds for all $h \in \overline{\operatorname{span} \mathscr{G}}$. For a proof using Egorov's theorem, one chooses $\mathscr{G}$ as a family of bounded functions that vanish outside some set of finite measure. Besides the family $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, another good choice would be the family of characteristic functions of sets of finite measure. The latter has the advantage that we can use that family on arbitrary measure spaces. The proof works the same for both families.

Now we come to your argument. You write

> $$\|\left(f_{n}-f\right)g\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\|g\|_{L^{1}\left(\text{supp}(g)\right)}\leq\|g\|\left(\int_{E}(f_{n}-f)\ dx+\int_{E^{c}}\left(f_{n}-f\right)\ dx\right),$$

and say you used Hölder's inequality. This may be a typo, but as written, it is incorrect. Hölder's inequality uses a pair of conjugate exponents, it doesn't bound the $L^1$-norm of a product by the product of $L^1$-norms. Since we're dealing with $L^2$-functions, a natural choice would be to take the $L^2$-norm of both factors. But that would lead to something including the integral

$$\int_E \lvert f_n - f\rvert^2\,dx,$$

and I don't know how to show that that is uniformly (in $n$) small for small $\varepsilon > 0$ without an assumption of uniform integrability of the $f_n$. It works better to use the $L^1$-norm for $f_n - f$ and the $L^{\infty}$-norm for $g$. Also, in the last integrals, you need to take the absolute value, $\lvert f_n - f\rvert$.

With the pair $(1,\infty)$ of conjugate exponents, we get the inequality

$$\lVert (f_n - f)g\rVert_{L^1} \leqslant \lVert g\rVert_{L^{\infty}}\Biggl(\int_E \lvert f_n - f\rvert\,dx + \int_{E^c} \lvert f_n - f\rvert\,dx\Biggr). \tag{2}$$

On the right hand side of $(2)$, we have

$$\int_{E^c}\lvert f_n - f\rvert\,dx \leqslant m(E^c)\sup \:\{ \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert : x \in E^c\} \leqslant m(\operatorname{supp} g)\sup \:\{ \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert : x \in E^c\},$$

and that tends to $0$ because of the uniform convergence on $E^c$. For the other integral, you state the bound

> $$\int_{E}\left(f_{n}-f\right)\ dx\leq2\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|m(E)<2\sup_{n}\|f_{n}\|\epsilon,$$

but that isn't correct. If, say, $f_n(x) = x^{-\alpha}\cdot \chi_{[1/n,1]}(x)$, and $E = [0,\varepsilon]$, then we have

$$\int_E \lvert f_n - f\rvert\,dx = \int_0^{\varepsilon} x^{-\alpha}\,dx = \frac{\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}$$

for $n \leqslant 1/\varepsilon$, and for every fixed $n$, that tends to $0$ slower than a constant multiple of $\varepsilon$. However, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields

$$\int_E \lvert f_n - f\rvert\,dx \leqslant \lVert f_n -f \rVert_2 \sqrt{m(E)} \leqslant 2S\sqrt{\varepsilon},$$

so we get the same type of inequality, just with a smaller exponent on $\varepsilon$. This then yields

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \:\lVert (f_n - f)g\rVert_{L^1} \leqslant M\sqrt{\varepsilon}$$

for every $\varepsilon > 0$, i.e. $\lVert (f_n - f)g\rVert_{L^1} \to 0$.

Comment: Oh wow. Your answer is very neat and noticeable. As you said, I made typo. And at the last statement, I'm shocked. I did the same mistake several times because I didn't know why people use Holder inequality to make a simple one difficult.:) I'm really happy to see someone like you who write a reply these neatly. It's my first time. Thank you.

Comment: And also, like in my question, I just ramdomly used 'dense subset theorem'. But as you mentioned, if I want to use dense subset theorem, I should make it clear why I can use the theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof that the hypothesis imply $f \in  {L}^{2} \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$. Let us consider the set
${A}_{k} = \left\{x \in  \left[{-k} , k\right] , \left|f \left(x\right)\right| \leqslant k\right\}$. Let
${\epsilon}  >  0$ and, according to Egoroff's theorem, let ${E}_{{\epsilon}} \subset  {A}_{k}$
be a set having measure $ \leqslant  {\epsilon}$
such that ${f}_{n} {{1}}_{{A}_{k}}$ converges uniformly to $f {{1}}_{{A}_{k}}$ on
${A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}$. Let ${d}_{n} = \sup  \left\{\left|{f}_{n} \left(x\right)-f \left(x\right)\right| , x \in  {A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}\right\}$
One has

$$\left|f {{1}}_{{A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}}\right|  \leqslant  \left|{f}_{n} {{1}}_{{A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}}\right|+{d}_{n} {{1}}_{{A}_{k}} \in  {L}^{2} \left({A}_{k}\right)$$

and

$${\left\|f {{1}}_{{A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}}\right\|}_{2}  \leqslant  {\left\|{f}_{n} {{1}}_{{A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}}\right\|}_{2}+{d}_{n} \sqrt{2 k}  \leqslant  M+{d}_{n} \sqrt{2 k}$$

By letting $n$ tend to  infinity, one deduces ${\left\|f {{1}}_{{A}_{k}  \setminus  {E}_{{\epsilon}}}\right\|}_{2}  \leqslant  M$
Now

$$\int_{{E}_{{\epsilon}}}^{}{\left|f\right|}^{2} d {\mu}  \leqslant  \int_{{E}_{{\epsilon}}}^{}{k}^{2} d {\mu}  \leqslant  {k}^{2} {\epsilon}$$

hence
${\left\|f {{1}}_{{A}_{k}}\right\|}_{2}  \leqslant  M+k \sqrt{{\epsilon}}$
By letting ${\epsilon}$ tend to 0, one deduces that ${\left\|f {{1}}_{{A}_{k}}\right\|}_{2}  \leqslant  M$. Since
${\left|f\right|}^{2} {{1}}_{{A}_{k}}$ converges monotonically to ${\left|f\right|}^{2}$ when $k \rightarrow  \infty $,
it follows that $f \in  {L}^{2} \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ and that ${\left\|f\right\|}_{2}  \leqslant  M$.

Comment: I thought that $f \in L^2(\Bbb{R})$ follows directly from Fatou's lemma: $$ \|f\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\Bbb{R}} \liminf_{n\to\infty} |f_n|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_{\Bbb{R}} |f_n|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \sup_{n} \| f_n \|_{L^2}^2. $$

Comment: Why did you prove this?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee All right sorry, it was not necessary. On the other hand, it is necessary to *say* that $f \in L^2$ because it's used to prove the result. Having said that, we may as well suppose that $f=0$ by taking $f_n - f$ instead of $f$.